# Display custom select form in "Quick View" window in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the code, that on the product editing page shows the checkbox "Roast Level". When the manager clicks on this checkbox, a select box appears on the page of a single product, allowing the customer to select "Roast Level".

When selecting and adding a product to the cart, the selected value appears in the cart itself. This value is also shown on the checkout page, on the "Thank You" page, in the order, on the email notification, and on the order editing page in the admin panel.

Here is the code:

```
// Display Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'roast_custom_field_add');

function roast_custom_field_add() {
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
            array(
                    'id' => '_roast_checkbox',
                    'label' => __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce'),
                    'description' => __('Enable roast level', 'woocommerce')
            )
    );
}

// Save Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'roast_custom_field_save');

function roast_custom_field_save($post_id) {
    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $roast_checkbox = isset($_POST['_roast_checkbox']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_roast_checkbox', esc_attr($roast_checkbox));
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
*Display Select Box
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_roast_custom_field', 0 );
function add_roast_custom_field() {
    global $product;

    // If is single product page and have the "roast_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( is_product() && $product->get_meta( '_roast_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="roast_select">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'roast_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Roast Level'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Please select',
                'Blue'  => 'Blue',
                'Rare'  => 'Rare',
                'Medium Rare'   => 'Medium Rare',
                'Medium'    => 'Medium',
                'Medium Well'   => 'Medium Well',
                'Well Done' => 'Well Done'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Add as custom cart item data
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 21 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['roast_custom_options'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['roast_option'] = wc_clean( $_POST['roast_custom_options'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'roast_custom_field', 10, 21 );
function roast_custom_field( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( isset($cart_item['roast_option']) ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>' . __("Roast Level", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['roast_option'] . '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Display roast custom fields values under item name in checkout
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 21 );
function roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['roast_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>' . __("Roast Level", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['roast_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Save chosen slelect field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_product_fitting_color', 10, 21 );
function save_order_item_product_fitting_color( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['roast_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['roast_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}   

add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_script');
function add_footer_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
       jQuery('#roast_custom_options').on('change',function(){
           var roast_level = jQuery(this).val();
           /*console.log(roast_level); */
           var button = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.add_to_cart_button'); console.log(button); 
           jQuery(button).attr('data-roast_custom_options',roast_level);
        });

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I need to add the “Roast Level” selection form to the quick view window, to the 
 [content-product-quick-view.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7NtSBhJFFFX1vDZzUf_66JCNvSs6BLq/view?usp=sharing) file.

When adding code, errors appeared. The form does not show, or the "Add to Cart" button disappears.

```
global $product;

// If is single product page and have the "roast_checkbox" enabled we display the field
if ( $product->get_meta( '_roast_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

    echo '<div class="roast_select">';

    $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'roast_custom_options', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Roast Level'),
        'required'      => false,
        'return'       => false,
        'options'   => array(
            ''      => 'Please select',
            'Blue'  => 'Blue',
            'Rare'  => 'Rare',
            'Medium Rare'   => 'Medium Rare',
            'Medium'    => 'Medium',
            'Medium Well'   => 'Medium Well',
            'Well Done' => 'Well Done'
        )
    ), '' );
    echo $select;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

As a result, I could not put this code in the php file. Perhaps here need to add additional code. And I ask for your help.

Comment: There is not such a thing named quick view in WC templates. `content-product-quick-view.php` is not a core WC or WP theme file. Without knowing about the theme you're using, and the source code of it, no one can help

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question, added a link to the PHP file.

Comment: Was not this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433513/12232340

Comment: As I wrote in my question, this code works on a single product page but does not work in the quick view window. That's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script in `add_footer_script` with this:

```
( function( $ ) {
   $( document ).ready( function() {
       $(document).on('change', '#roast_custom_options' ,function() {
           $('.add_to_cart_button').data('roast_custom_options', this.value)
       });
   });
 }( jQuery ) );
```

if you are using ajax, you must subscribe via the parent container or document. To pass custom field using data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That template already has the variable product and and you're redeclaring it.   Remove `global $product` from it the code you added to content-product-quick-view.php file and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I left `$ GLOBALS ['product'] = $product;` and deleted `global $product;` Unfortunately, nothing has changed.

Comment: There is nothing in the debug.log file

Comment: Do you have access to the server php error logs? usually in /var/logs/

Comment: I contacted tech support. There are no errors today.

Comment: Lol. They'd at least have some warnings if they bothered to check. I have to work for a bit but I'll circle back in a couple hours and take a closer look.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but return = false in the args should make the woocommerce_form_field echo out, not return.